# NuGet keeps ignoring "allowedVersion"

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget

I'm using NuGet in VS 2013 and try to limit the JQuery Package to version 1.x (instead of 2.x)
Here is what I have in my packages.conf

```
<package id="jQuery" version="1.11.2" targetFramework="net45" allowedVersion="[1,2)" />
```

Which to my knowledge tells nuget to exclude versions starting with ***2***

Now, when I run the following command in the console to see what would be updated.

```
Update-Package -ProjectName Website -WhatIf
```

it shows me

```
Updating 'jQuery' from version '1.11.2' to '2.1.3' in project 'Website'.
Remove 'jQuery 1.11.2' from project Website.
Add 'jQuery 2.1.3' to project Website.
```

Which is not what I expected. Why does nuget want to update to version 2.1.3 even when I said exclude this version.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not working because the [attribute](https://docs.nuget.org/create/versioning#constraining-upgrades-to-allowed-versions) should be **allowedVersions** and not allowedVersion. The following entry in the packages.config file should as you are expecting it to.

```
<package id="jQuery" version="1.11.2" targetFramework="net45" allowedVersions="[1,2)" />
```

Comment: those typos... Thank you

Comment: There have been a couple of [bugs](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/333) with NuGet 3.0 in VS 2015 where this feature was broken.

Comment: Doesn't work in VS2013 even with the attribute named correctly

Comment: Works OK for me in VS 2013. Update-Package updates to the latest version allowed by the constraint. The Updates tab only shows the latest version compatible with the constraint. The only thing that does not work is if you explicitly install a later version from the Online tab which NuGet seems to allow you to do.